# How should I calculate $||\underline{u}-\underline{w}||_{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I'm trying to calculate $||\underline{u}-\underline{w}||_{2}$ where:

$$
u=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\
2 & 2\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,\,\, w=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\
2 & 2\\
1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm not familiar with the $|| \cdot ||_2$ operator and I'm not sure how to search it in the search engine. How should I calculate $||\underline{u}-\underline{w}||_{2}$?

Comment: Should $u$ and $w$ be regarded as matrices?

Comment: @JensRenders Yes.

Comment: Then what you need is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms). The 2-norm is what you are asking about and it is equal to the largest singular value of your matrix.

Comment: What is $\underline{u}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Matrix Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) $\|\cdot\|_p$ given by $$\|A\|_p:=\max_{|x|_p=1}|Ax|_p$$ where $|x|_p$ is the vector norm. In particular for $p=2,$ $$\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^*A)}$$ where $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $A.$

Comment: @vesii Note it is not $A \cdot A$ but $A^* A$ where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A.$ Hence it is a $2 \times 3$ matrix and so multiplication is well defined.

Comment: Yeah, just read about it in the wikipedia. Thank you for you help!